# Work done moving a charge- does the path matter?

Tags: electrostatics

Let's say we have a right triangle ABC and the right angle is on A. We place a charge +Q on A and a charge +2Q on B.

Moving the +Q charge from A to C do I do the same work regardless of the path? If I move the charge around before putting it on C I definitely do more work , don't I?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on how to solve this?
 Writing them out  will help you get a hint, as this is not a homework solving website.

Comment: My question is theoretical. I can't elaborate on 'does the path matter' . I thought that if I moved the charge a thousand circles before putting it on C I would definitely do more work . And it is not homework . I'm just practicing by myself so I'm only asking to learn.

Comment: Hi John, I'm not being pedantic with you, it actually it right tag for homework like question as well, like yours. Anyway, could you read this page regarding conserved forces and work. http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circuits/Lesson-1/Electric-Field-and-the-Movement-of-Charge